# How to formulate Regular Expression correctly in Oracle that works in other engines

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

Need help if formulating a regular expression that will work in Oracle.  And if someone knows of a regular expression tester specifically for oracle, that will also help.

I am trying the following regex

```
^([A-Za-z]{2,4})([\s0]*)([1-9][0-9]{0,5})([\s]*)([A-Za-z]?)$
```

on `APLS   0000    1024  C`,  I get the correct results with [this](https://regex101.com/) tester, but when I try the below in Oracle, it doesn't return 'YES' as expected .

```
select 'Yes' from dual where REGEXP_Like
     ('APLS   0000    1024  C',  '^([A-Za-z]{2,4})([\s]*)([0]*)([1-9][0-9]{0,5})([\s]*)([A-Za-z]?)$');
```

So, I am trying to understand how to make it work in Oracle, where I will be able to get the 3 tokens - APLS, 1024 and C' when I replace the REGEXP_LIKE with REGEXP_REPLACE, of course with appropriate changes in the SQL statement.

Thanks

Comment: Could you include some tests which passed but now fail on Oracle?  Are there _any_ inputs which actually still pass?

Comment: The above test `'APLS   0000    1024  C'` passed in the linked regex engine, but failed in Oracle.   Also `APLS1024C` passed in Oracle as well as the above linked online tester engine.

Comment: The answer given by @collapsar looks good, and you should try it.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I am in the process of testing it against various data.  Will post the results

Comment: Yes, @collapsar's explanation was clear and the updated regular expression worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have 2 issues with your regex:

- regex wouldn't match your test string.
- `\s` cannot be used in character classes.

You have ...

```
^([A-Za-z]{2,4})([\s]*)([0]*)([1-9][0-9]{0,5})([\s]*)([A-Za-z]?)$
                   ^         ^                   ^
                   |         |                   +-- problem #2 (2nd instance)
                   |         +--- problem #1: you need to match a whitespace sequence here
                   +--- problem #2: escape sequence used in character class
```

Instead take ...

```
^([A-Za-z]{2,4})(\s*)([0]*)(\s*)([1-9][0-9]{0,5})(\s*)([A-Za-z]?)$
```